# $\sqrt{I}+\sqrt{J}=R$ implies $I+J=R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $I,J$ ideals of $R$. Suppose that
$$
\sqrt{I}+\sqrt{J}=R
$$
I want to show that this implies $I+J=R$.

Take $r\in R$, then I can write 
$$
r=a+b,
$$
for some $a\in \sqrt{I}, b\in \sqrt{J}$. This implies that there exist $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that $a^n\in I, b^m\in J$. Consider 
$$r^{m+n}=(a+b)^{m+n}=\sum_{i=0}^{m+n} \binom{m+n}{i} a^i b^{m+n-i}.$$

Now, in $a^i b^{m+n-i}$ either $i\leq n$ and $b^{m+n-i}\in J$, so that $a^i b^{m+n-i}\in J$ or $i\geq n$ so that $a^i\in I$ and $a^i b^{m+n-i}\in I$. This means that 
$$
r^{m+n}=c+d,
$$
where $c\in I, d\in J$. This decomposition should work for any $r\in R$, take $r=1$, then 
$$
1=c+d
$$
with $c\in I, d\in J$. Let $r\in R$, then $$
r=1\cdot r=(c+d)r=cr+dr \in I+J,
$$
since $cr\in I, dr\in J$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: This has been asked before. Surf the [abstract-algebra] tag a little.

Comment: Yes, the proof is correct.

Comment: Looks fine. Another way of organizing it: $\sqrt I + \sqrt J \subseteq \sqrt{I + J}$, and $1 \in \sqrt{K}$ iff $1 \in K$. Here the binomial stuff is hidden in the use of the fact that the radical of an ideal is an ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this proof is correct.  It can be shortened slightly by just using $1$ for the decomposition instead of an arbitrary $r$, but that's an issue of style.